# SoundCloud HTML embed on Chrome for Android

Tags: android, ios, embed, soundcloud

I'm trying to embed the SoundCloud player on a web app using the recommended embed code. However, when Android users tap the big orange Play on SoundCloud button, they are presented with a "There was a problem loading that URL." message if they have the SoundCloud app installed (if they don't have the app installed, they get jumped to the Google Play store). When users tap the button on iOS, they are taken to the SoundCloud webpage in Mobile Safari where they can play the track. This happens with every track I've tried and I've reproduced this on Chrome on Android 5 and 6. Here's the embed code I'm using:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/18942763&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe>
```

https://codepen.io/gmusick/full/WojpeZ/

Anyone from SoundCloud have any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: I noticed this, but via `<amp-soundcloud>` on AMP pages, e.g. https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-soundcloud/  The problem seems to be that the URL that is ultimately launched by Android is of the form `intent://tracks:123456789#Intent;scheme=soundcloud;package=com.soundcloud.android;end` and that isn't recognized by the native app. This is a strange intent URI, as it's "abusing" the hostname and port to pass the track ID to the native app, rather than using an Intent extra.